# Verilog module not being called

Tags: verilog, icarus

I'm working on a program that will take a value in BCD, convert it to binary, and count down for the given value to 0. The BCD conversion module works perfectly, but it seems my 'microwave' module is not being called.

My output of this program is:

```
time = xxxxxxxx bcdtime = 0001 0010

time = 00001100 bcdtime = 0001 0010
```

I can see the conversion, but the countdown does not occur. Can anyone explain where I might be going wrong or point me in the direction of resources that could help me answer this? My code is below:

```
module bcd_to_bin(bintime,bcdtime1,bcdtime0);
  input [3:0] bcdtime1,bcdtime0;
  output [7:0] bintime;

  assign bintime = (bcdtime1 * 4'b1010) + {3'b0, bcdtime0};
endmodule

module microwave(bintimeout, Clk, Start, Stop, bintime, status);
    input [7:0] bintime;
    input Clk, Start, Stop;
    output reg [7:0] bintimeout;
    output reg status;
    
    
 always @ (posedge Start)
    begin
        assign bintimeout = bintime;
    end 
    
 always @ (posedge Clk)

  begin 
    bintimeout = bintimeout - 1;
  end
endmodule


module t_microwave;

    wire status;
    wire [7:0] bintimeout;
    reg Clk=1; reg Start, Stop;
    reg [3:0] bcdtime1, bcdtime0;
    wire [7:0] bintime;
    
    microwave M2 (bintimeout, Clk, Start, Stop, bintime, status);
    bcd_to_bin M3 (bintime,bcdtime1,bcdtime0);
    
    
    
     always #10 Clk = ~Clk;
    initial
      begin
        
        Start = 0; Stop = 0; bcdtime1 = 4'b0001; bcdtime0 = 4'b0010;
        #10 Start = 1; #10 Start = 0;

        
      end       

    initial #10000 $finish;

    initial
      begin
        $monitor ("time = %b, bcdtime = %b %b ", bintimeout, bcdtime1, bcdtime0);
      end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

If you want to guarantee that your design captures the `Start` pulse, you should make sure it is high for one clock period (20).  Change:

```
    #10 Start = 1; #10 Start = 0;
```

to:

```
    #10 Start = 1; #20 Start = 0;
```

In the `microwave` module, you should assign to `bintimeout` in one `always` block, not two, and there is no need to use the `assign` keyword inside an `always` block.  Also, good coding practices recommend using nonblocking assignments (`<=`) for sequential logic.  This is a better way to code the module:

```
module microwave(bintimeout, Clk, Start, Stop, bintime, status);
    input [7:0] bintime;
    input Clk, Start, Stop;
    output reg [7:0] bintimeout;
    output reg status;
    
    always @ (posedge Clk) begin
        if (Start) begin
            bintimeout <= bintime;
        end else begin
            bintimeout <= bintimeout - 1;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

This is the output now, which shows the count-down:

```
time = xxxxxxxx, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00001100, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00001011, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00001010, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00001001, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00001000, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00000111, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00000110, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00000101, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00000100, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00000011, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00000010, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00000001, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 00000000, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 11111111, bcdtime = 0001 0010 
time = 11111110, bcdtime = 0001 0010
```